# How do I change the VM size of the agent pool in an Azure container service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-container-service, azure-vm-scale-set

I have deployed an Azure Container Service a month ago and it works perfectly. However when I tried to increase the VM count in the agent pool then Azure returned an "operation not allowed" error all the time.

This is the error returns -

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"OperationNotAllowed\",\r\n    \"target\": \"vmSize\",\r\n    \"**message\": \"Unable to perform Operation 'Update VM' on the VM because the requested size Standard_D2_v2 is not available in the cluster where the availability set is currently allocated**. The available sizes are: Basic_A0,Basic_A1,Basic_A2,Basic_A3,Basic_A4,Standard_A0,Standard_A1,Standard_A2,Standard_A3,Standard_A4,Standard_A5,Standard_A6,Standard_A7,Standard_D1,Standard_D2,Standard_D3,Standard_D4,Standard_D11,Standard_D12,Standard_D13,Standard_D14,Standard_A1_v2,Standard_A2_v2,Standard_A4_v2,Standard_A8_v2,Standard_A2m_v2,Standard_A4m_v2,Standard_A8m_v2. Read more on VM resizing strategy at https://aka.ms/azure-resizevm.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}

So according to the above error, it tells me to update the VM size of the agent pool. Is there a solution for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me which VM size of your original VM?  Use managed disk or unmanaged disk?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT VM size is Standard_D2_v2 and use managed disk

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT yes it is HDD

Comment: Change to size standard_D?_v2?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT This error occurred when I tried to increase VM count. (see first image). So actually I want to know where I can update VM size of agent pool?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, we can find the VM(agent) in your resource group, and select size to resize VM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157253/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-mugzi).

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Thanks for the reply , however manually we can change vm size in each VM but it will not change the agent pools VM size.

Comment: Does Azure CLI 2.0 work for you?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Nope it didnt work - (this is the process, I followed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-scale)

Comment: Please check the api version in that `automation script`, thanks:)

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT its "apiVersion": "2016-03-30"

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/Azure/ACS/issues/16).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug on the service side. We changed the default Master VM size and that's causing a problem in scaling the existing cluster whose default VM size may be `Standard_D2`. We are rolling out the fix. It should be done later this week.

BTW, in general you can change agent count in ACS, but you cannot change the VM size.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the core limit on your subscription.

Please check the limit and count for your subscription. You can request to increase the number of cores for the subscription.

Refer to *[Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits)*. I hope that might be the issue here.